# Why aren't static functions recognized in TypeScript mixins?

Tags: typescript

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
type Constructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

class MyClass {
  public static styles: string[];
}

const MyMixin = <T extends Constructor<MyClass>>(superClass: T): T => class extends superClass {
  public static override get styles(): string[] {
    return [];
  }
};
```

Compiling throws:

> TS4113: This member cannot have an 'override' modifier because it is not declared in the base class 'MyClass'.

Why? `styles` is definitely declared in `MyClass`. Instance functions work, but no static ones.

My guess is that this is to do with a general TypeScript rule that has probably already been covered in another post I cannot find.

Comment: Does this question depend on `lit` (or whatever "`ReactiveElement`" is)? If so you should tag the question as such so you get the right eyes on it; if not you should probably [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates your issue.  How should we proceed?

Comment: Maybe you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2plbm)?

Comment: See this https://catchts.com/oop-style article for typing mixin

Comment: Not every `Constructor<MyClass>` will have a `styles` property for the (possibly surprising) reason that a class whose instances are structurally compatible that `MyClass` will be seen as a `Constructor<MyClass>` by the compiler, even if they are not related by inheritance.  The fix is to require that `T` have a `styles` property.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXzeQm) for the problem and the recommended fix.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

https://tsplay.dev/wXzeQm

Comment: @vera Your code causes `TS2509: Base constructor return type 'never' is not an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.` on `extends superClass`.

Comment: @Oliver That is so odd since I do not get that error in the playground... or did you get that error when trying to adapt it to your code?

Comment: My own code. I cannot create a MRE for it.

Comment: @Oliver could you tell me if [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzeQm) works for you or not?

Comment: @jcalz It does, but it isn't a general solution.

Comment: Hmm, it’s as general as I can make it given your example. Can you elaborate, ideally by [edit]ing the example code with a use case unsatisfied by the approach I took?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript's type system does not currently have built-in support for mixins, which can make it difficult to correctly type the members of a class that is created using a mixin.

In your specific example, the override keyword is causing a compile error because TypeScript doesn't know that the styles property exists on the ReactiveElement class.

One way to work around this limitation is to use a utility that creates a new class that extends the original class and adds the desired members, instead of using a mixin directly. This utility should ensure that the original class's type is preserved and that the new members are correctly typed.

An alternative is to use another way of code reuse such as composition over inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you just describing inheritance in your third paragraph? Can you please add an example?